# Azure Logic Apps - Oracle Connector - Execute a query

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am working on an Azure Logic Apps integration which insert data into an on-premise Oracle Database.
I can successfully run the Logic Apps integration and insert the data into our Oracle table (a custom staging table).

I would like to run a truncate on that table before inserting the new data.
I added the **Oracle - Execute a Oracle Query** component and then provided the following query:
TRUNCATE TABLE .<TABLE_NAME>;

After deploying to Azure, the integration failed on the Execute a Oracle Query with error:

```
"message": "BadGateway",
"innerError": {
"status": 502,
"message": "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.\r\n inner exception: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed....",
```

If I remove the **Execute a Oracle Query** component, the **Oracle Insert row** component works fine.
I am not sure why it says the gateway may not be installed. I suspect it's a *badly trapped* error message.

Is that how the **Execute a Oracle Query** is supposed to be used?
Otherwise, how can I execute the truncate or how can I debug this error message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle Connector for Azure Logic Apps does not support `DDL`. The exception you are getting is the generic one in Azure Logic Apps. I honestly believe the exception handler module is not very reliable here, because it usually goes to the gateway issue when the problem has no relation whatsoever. However, you have the option to overcome this limitation by using a call to an stored procedure.

In Oracle

```
create or replace procedure pr_trc_table ( ptab in varchar2 )
is 
begin 
  execute immediate 'truncate table '||ptab||' ' ;
exception when others then raise;
end;
/
```

This [Oracle Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/oracle/) developed by Microsoft has a lot of limitations, which is normal as they try to ensure you use their own Azure SQL Service.

- When invoking a Stored Procedure on an Oracle server, we have the following limitations:
- OUT parameters are not supported currently.
- Return value is not available since Oracle Stored Procedure does not return any result.
- Oracle Functions are not supported so they are not listed in the UI.
- The response size limit is 8MB.
- The request size limit is 2MB.
- Oracle native query is supported with the following limitations:
- RefCursor is not supported.
- OUT parameters are not supported.
- Only one result set can be returned.
- Gateway version 3000.63.4 (October release) or later is required.
- Minimum supported version for Oracle Data Access Client is version 11

Besides, if any oracle query or stored procedure execution time exceeds 110 seconds, the action will timeout. Insert and update to a table does not return the full item, it returns only the input properties for the operation. A Primary Key is required to get deterministic paging result for `GetRows` operation.

Comment: Hello @RobertoHernandez, ah ... I did read the MS Oracle Connector documentation and the limitation but didn't see anything specifying DDL is not supported. In that case, why are they even providing "Execute a Oracle Query" if they have "Execute stored procedure"? What can you do with the "Execute a Oracle query" component if DDL is not supported?

Comment: @Hunkerjr, I know they don't say it. But I was part of an Azure implementation with Oracle on premises for my current customer, and it was confirmed to us by the Microsoft Engineer. I can tell you that all reasons summarize in one: move from Oracle to Azure SQL Service. That is the driven business model. **Keep in mind that the connector is not from Oracle, it is from Microsoft**

Comment: I wish I could give you the note from the MS engineer, but it is a proprietary document of my customer and I am not allowed to do it

Comment: I am not arguying with you ;) As you said, it all make sense. Thank you for the info!

Comment: @Hunkerjr, thanks to you. In my case, we decided finally not to use Azure Logic Apps when the database is Oracle, as there are many issues with the connector. Good luck !